# simultaneous ajax requests django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I have multiple ajax calls firing on page load.

From `request1` I expect `response1`, and from `request2` I expect `response2`. But I receive `response1` for both `request1` and `request2`.

When I move `request2` to fire after `response1` has been recieved then I recieve `request2` as expected.

How can I do multiple ajax calls safely?

some code:

```
//avoids problem
    this.update = function(){
        $.post('/ws/newsfeed/', {'action':'6'}).done( function(response){
            ...
            _this.get_alert_count()
        })
    }

    this.get_alert_count = function(){
        $.post('/ws/newsfeed/', {'action':'2'}).done(function(count) {
            ...
        })
    }

_this.update()

//causes problem
    this.update = function(){
        $.post('/ws/newsfeed/', {'action':'6'}).done( function(response){
             ...
        })
    }

    this.get_alert_count = function(){
        $.post('/ws/newsfeed/', {'action':'2'}).done(function(count) {
            ...
        })
    }

_this.update()
_this.get_alert_count()
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you post some sample code? That might be helpful!

Comment: Have you tried running Firebug to inspect the requests and responses to make sure you don't have bugs in your JS?

Comment: @Spacedman using chrome. I have checked dev tools yes. You can see how simple the code is though above - no bugs.

Comment: How do we know there's no bugs in your "..."? This is not a reproducible example.

Comment: the "response1" and "response2" are the responses received from the server before any processing from "...", that's how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to investigate AjaxQ (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/), it lets you chain ajax calls without overlapping in a given time.

Hope it helps

Comment: just bear in mind that the order of your ajax requests doesn't insure that the respective responses will be in the same order. This is where ajaxq come for.